# Gesture to switch between IE tabs

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, modern-ui, gestures

I have the Yoga 2 pro (touchscreen convertible). In tent or stand mode, with no access to the keyboard, what is the quickest way to switch between open tabs in Internet Explorer (running in Modern UI)?

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate, however ideally I'd like to know a gesture-based solution.

Comment: On my Windows 8.1 machines they are right there to just tap on.